# JavaScript sudoku solver is stuck in infinite loop for some boards/doesn't work for all boards

Tags: javascript, backtracking, sudoku, brute-force

I am new to stackoverflow. I searched for related questions, but none seems to answer my questions. I am in my first semester of Computer Science and am currently taking the Programming 1 course. We only work with JavaScript for the whole course and so JavaScript is the only programming language I know, so far. Consequently, I have a fairly limited understanding, intuitive or otherwise, of programming at large. English is also not my first language, so forgive me for mistakes.

Nonetheless, here's my problem: I need to program a sudoku solver. I have actually succeeded in coding a solver for a sudoku which is considered "easy". It takes a fraction of a second to do it, so I am fairly content with the results. The problem is: there are some sudokus which do not work, namely the ones who are considered "hard". Needless to say, the solver needs to work for all sudokus. Below are snippets of code for examples of both "easy" and "hard" sudoku boards, as well the code for my solver. I tried to annotate as best I could to describe the functioning, but there is clearly a problem since it will not solve the hard one. It is actually stuck in an infinite loop.

```js
var easyBoard = [
    [1,0,0,3,0,0,9,5,2],
    [0,4,0,6,0,0,1,0,0],
    [3,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,6,4,7,2,0,0,1,0],
    [8,7,0,9,0,6,0,2,4],
    [0,2,0,0,8,5,7,6,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,7],
    [0,0,7,0,0,9,0,4,0],
    [2,3,9,0,0,4,0,0,1]  
];

var hardBoard = [
    [4,0,0,6,0,7,0,8,5],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0],
    [0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,5,0,0,0,3,0,0,4],
    [3,7,0,0,0,8,0,0,0],
    [6,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
    [8,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0],
    [0,3,1,0,4,9,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9]
];


var solve = function (board) {
    var empty = []; // We create an array for the 1x1 squares with no value, so we can call upon them with ease later on.
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] === 0) {
                empty.push([i,j]);
            }
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < empty.length;) { // We check every possible value for all empty 1x1 squares.
        var row = empty[i][0]; // Used for row and 3x3 square checks
        var column = empty[i][1]; // Used for column and 3x3 square checks
        var value = board[row][column] + 1; // We start at 1, because obviously 0 is not a Sudoku value.
        var found = false; // We assume the value is invalid, unless it passes all three tests.
        while (!found && value <= 9) { // As long as the value is invalid, we increase by one until it reaches more than 9.
            var equal = false; // We assume for now that the value is not equal to any other in its row, column or 3x3 square.
            for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                if (board[row][y] === value) {
                    equal = true;
                }
            }
            for (var x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                if (board[x][column] === value) {
                    equal = true;
                }
            }
            for (var x = 3*Math.floor(row/3); x < 3*Math.floor(row/3)+3; x++) {
                for (var y = 3*Math.floor(column/3); y < 3*Math.floor(column/3)+3; y++) {
                    if (board[x][y] === value) {
                        equal = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!equal) { // If the value is not equal to any other in its row, column or 3x3 square, it is valid.
                found = true; // We have found a valid value, for now.
                board[row][column] = value; // We assign said value to the corresponding board 1x1 square, for now.
                i++; // We then move on to the next empty 1x1 square.
            }
            else {
                value++; // If the value is invalid, we simply try the next possible value.
            }
        }
        if (!found) { // If, from 1 to 9, the value is invalid, it means the one before is invalid.
            board[row][column] = 0; // We then re-assign an empty value to the 1x1 square, before backtracking.
            i--; // We go back to the previous 1x1 square to try a different value.
        }
    }
};

//   test routines

var clone2 = array => array.slice().map( row=>row.slice());

function easyTest() {
    var board = clone2( easyBoard);
    solve( board);
    console.log( "easy board solution:");
    console.log( board);
}

function hardTest() {
    var board = clone2( hardBoard);
    solve( board);
    console.log( "hard board solution:");
    console.log( board);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="easyTest()">Easy Test</button>
<button type="button" onclick="hardTest()">Hard Test</button>
```

The code works for the first one, but not the second. Is it because a backtracking/brute-force algorithm is not fast enough for the "hard" sudoku? Is it that it will just take several hours or is there an issue within my code which causes a problem with the first board, but not the second?

I am sorry if something is not clear, and I swear I have tried understanding the answers to other similar questions, but all of them contained several notions or operators/objects or whatever which I have no knowledge of. If someone could point out the problems within my code, and tell me if it is possible to solve the second board with it or if I need another method altogether.

Thank you so much in advance!

P.S.: A lot of people talk about objects within JavaScript, or object-oriented programming. I don't know if it's relevant, but we haven't seen any of that yet.

Comment: You should look into a recursive function that is able to walk and process only a small subset of the board every tick, and use setTimout on the next iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. Isn't recursiveness the same thing as backtracking? I'm trying to understand: so, I need to tell the program to do only a certain part of the board, but not more than that, and for a limited amount of time? Is it because the code takes too much time and is actually stuck in a dead-end where there are so many possibilities that I should set a timer to end it for that part? What if the part that takes so much time is actually the right way and leads to a solution? Maybe what I said makes absolutely no sense, but I'm just not sure if I understand your comment.

Comment: I was referring to the part where you talk about long execution times. This wouldn't help if you hit a dead end, but it does get around limitations of JS on various systems. One system might halt while a different system works just fine.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. The problem appears to be the computer at university. I've edited the code snippet so you can actually run it on your laptop or PC to see it work.  My 64 bit but slow laptop took 8 seconds to  run 100 million loop iterations that called out to a no-operation function - which would add up to at least 400 million instruction steps by my count

Comment: Damn, the guy with the answer below says it took him about 10 seconds as well. The thing is, I'm running the solve right now, and it says it's at slightly over 1 billion steps...are steps the same thing as loop iterations? I don't think so, 'cause when I run step by step, the step tick goes up by 1 every time the cursor moves in the code, so I'm probably way below 100 million actual loop iterations. Also, the professor uses said server-based program to read the code, so I need to find a code that will run using that. You know what? Screw brute force. I'll try constrain propagation instead.

Comment: Time to start all over! XD

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right. The code you posted solved the "hard" board in 1800 **milliseconds**. After some optimization I got that down to around 300 **milliseconds** on the same Windows laptop used for testing.

I'm providing the optimized version here to test if the uni computer can run it *if you wish to try*. I am quite wary of suggesting doing so if you are still working on a brute force solution, but it is certainly a version of your code!

In the end you may be able to test if the uni computer is simply not allowing brute force algorithms sufficient time to complete (or implements an instruction "step" limit in a custom JS engine it runs).

```js
function emptyCells( board) {
    var empty = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] === 0) {
                var boxRow = 3* Math.floor( i/3);
                var boxCol = 3* Math.floor( j/3);
                empty.push([i,j, boxRow, boxCol]);
            }
        }
    }
    return empty;
}

function isUnique( board, empty, value) {
    var row, col;

    // test row
    row = board[empty[0]];
    for( col = 0; col < 9; ++ col) {
        if( value == row[col]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // test col
    col = empty[1];
    for( var row = 0; row < 9; ++row) {
        if( value == board[ row][col]){
            return false;
        } 
    }
    // test box
    var boxRow = empty[2];
    var boxCol = empty[3];
    for( var i = 3; i--;) {
        row = board[ boxRow++];
        for( var j = 3; j--;) {
            if( row[boxCol + j] == value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var solve = function (board) {
    var empty = emptyCells( board);

    nextEmpty:
    for (var i = 0; i < empty.length;) { // We check every possible value for all empty 1x1 squares.
        var row = empty[i][0]; // Used for row and 3x3 square checks
        var column = empty[i][1]; // Used for column and 3x3 square checks
        var value = board[row][column] + 1; // We start at 1, because obviously 0 is not a Sudoku value.   
        var cell = empty[i];

        while (value <= 9) { // test values up to 9.
            if( isUnique( board, cell, value)) {
                board[row][column] = value; // We assign said value to the corresponding board 1x1 square, for now.
                i++; // Move on to the check next empty cell.
                continue nextEmpty;
            }
            value++; // If the value is invalid, we simply try the next possible value.    
        }

        board[row][column] = 0;
        if( i == 0) {  // board is not solvable
            return null;
        }
        i--; // We go back to the previous 1x1 square to try a different value.
    }
    return board;
};
var board = [
    [4,0,0,6,0,7,0,8,5],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0],
    [0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,5,0,0,0,3,0,0,4],
    [3,7,0,0,0,8,0,0,0],
    [6,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0],
    [8,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0],
    [0,3,1,0,4,9,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9]
];
var t0 = Date.now();
solve(board);
var t1 = Date.now();
console.log( " in " + (t1-t0) + "ms");
console.log( board.map( row=> row.join(',')).join('\n'));
console.log( "\n solved in " + (t1-t0) + "ms");
```

Comment: Yeah, something's up. I believe "the uni computer is simply not allowing brute force algorithms sufficient time to complete (or implements an instruction "step" limit in a custom JS engine it runs)". It has to be on purpose. They know we'd want to go the easy way and do brute force. ;) Anyway, thank you very much for your help, at least you tried and it probably saved me some valuable time in the end!

Answer (score 0):

The second one gets solved on my computer in ~ 10 seconds

```
[4, 9, 3, 6, 1, 7, 2, 8, 5]
[2, 8, 5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]
[1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 4, 9, 3]
[9, 5, 8, 1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 4]
[3, 7, 2, 4, 9, 8, 1, 5, 6]
[6, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 9, 3, 8]
[8, 4, 9, 5, 2, 6, 3, 1, 7]
[5, 3, 1, 7, 4, 9, 8, 6, 2]
[7, 2, 6, 3, 8, 1, 5, 4, 9]
```

Comment: Truly? You solved it in 10 seconds using my code? Just for fun, is it possible for you to tell me the number of "steps" the program has taken? We use a server-based JavaScript reader developed at our university, but the computers in the lab are probably quite slow compared to yours. When I load the program, it gets 100 million steps in about one minute. I don't know if that is excrutiatingly slow and if that's why I'm unable to solve the sudoku. Do you think the computer performance has anything to do with it? Just to be clear, did you actually use my code to do it?

Comment: yeah, i used your code. 866396 steps for the hard one.

Comment: What the actual ****? Why does my computer get to 1 billion steps then? XD

Is it about memory or something? Like, not just the processing power...I don't know if you understand what I mean...it should take me 866396 steps as well, just maybe a little bit more time. I'm currently working on a constraint propagation/elimination process function to circumvent the problem, but if I could understand why my brute-force doesn't work for the second function, that'd be great and it would mean I could use it! I'm gonne use the updated code the guy above did.

Comment: Yeah, like the guy above said, it's probably "the uni computer is simply not allowing brute force algorithms sufficient time to complete (or implements an instruction "step" limit in a custom JS engine it runs)". Bastards knew we'd wanna do backtracking instead of constraint propagation. THEY KNOW OUR EVERY MOOOVE